# Android: how to create application frame controls

Tags: android, android-layout

We have an Android application made of menu of modules and each module has the same layout as on this picture:

[image: module layout]

You have a header with module name and two buttons on the bottom. The module itself is behind those three transparent elements. Left button allows the user to move to the previous screen and right button gets him back to the menu with modules. Text in header changes based on current screen action.

My question is how to build the module transparent frame. Is it possible to have one layout in Android on top of the other? Should we design the code as a parent class that would be inherited by all the modules? I am interested in some best practice. I have experience with Java but only theoretical knowledge of Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepare a separate common layout and use  to add that layout to as many layouts you want.

for more details check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Comment: Is it possible to have one layout in Android on top of the other? Will there be any problem with transparency of the top layout?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are so called [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). These Fragments are sort of like `Activities`, with their own layouts and lifecycles, but you are able to use multiple `Fragments` at once. This means you'll be able to use one `Fragment` for your navigation and header, and one for the module behind it.